# Meaning of the phrase "not until later" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/8TN3ebiVPNw). It is at 1 minute and one second. Here is the context:

> Jerry has just got a job as a junior stock broker and his boss invites him to have a drink after the 4 P.M. bell. He had a dinner date planned with his wife for her birthday, but that is **not until a bit later** and he figures he will be done by then.

Could you please rephrase the whose sentence for me? The phrase *not until later* really confuses me. Does Jerry realize that he will be done before his wife's birthday or after? He will be done later after what? Would it not be well just say Jerry had a dinner date planned with his wife for her birthday, but later he figures he will he done by then because he his boss invited for a drink? Or Jerry realizes that he will be done after he has a drink with his boss that he will be done by the beginning of the dinner with his wife?

Comment: Curious, was your confusion the result of not understanding that **that** is a demonstrative pronoun in this sentence, whose antecedent is "a dinner date.."? Or is it the phrase **not until**?

Comment: You are right "that" is the culprit of me not understanding that excerpt

Comment: He figures/thinks that since ***that*** (= the dinner date) won't happen until ***a bit later*** (=some time after) the "late afternoon" drink with the boss, he will have time to do the "boss drink" thing first, before he has to get ready and take his wife out to dinner as planned later in the evening. I don't see where you get ideas about the two events being linked by "because".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Later" should be understood in reference to "after the 4 PM bell". The boss has invited him to have a drink at a specific time; Jerry's dinner date with his wife occurs long enough after that point that he believes the drink with his boss will be over in time for him to make the date.

It might be clearer if we substitute a more specific time in place of "a bit later":

> He had a dinner date planned... but that was not until *7 PM*.

If you have a date planned for 7 PM, it's safe to assume that a 4 PM drink will not make you late.

Comment: Yes, in short **that** refers to the dinner date with his wife.

Answer (score 1):

**Not until a bit later** means that the date is not starting at the same time as the drinks. **A bit later** refers to an unspecified, normally small-ish, period of time - "I leave work at 5 o'clock, but I don't get home until a bit later" means that I have to factor in the time to drive home from work.

Jerry is thinking that, although he does have another appointment (the date), the time taken for the drinks should not interfere with it.